# How should I configure the TRQ pin on the DRV8847 Dual H-Bridge motor driver for Independent Bridge Interface mode?

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor, h-bridge, motordriver

I'm looking into motor drivers for a design update and I'm leaning towards using the [DRV8847PWPR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8847.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1688035138113). If I go with it, I intend to configure it for an Independent Bridge Interface (shown in section 7.3.34 of datasheet, image on page 26) to mimic the control interface of the [L293D](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/04/ac/22/f9/20/5d/43/a1/CD00000059.pdf/files/CD00000059.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000059.pdf). However, it is unclear how (or even if) I am supposed to connect the TRQ pin.

[image: DRV8847 independent bridge interface]

The TRQ pin is referred to as a "torque current scalar" and is used to set a "PWM trip current" for current regulation (see section 7.3.4, page 27 of linked datasheet for elaboration). Setting the pin to high will give a torque scalar of 100%, while setting the pin to low will give a torque scalar of 50%.

Given that the TRQ scalar value is related to certain resistors (referred to as Rsense12 &Rsense34 respectively) that are deliberately omitted from the Independent Bridge Interface configuration, and that it isn't mentioned anywhere in the configuration, I'm given to believe that the pin is meant to be left floating. However, the datasheet does specify which pins are to be left floating when setting the driver to this configuration, and it doesn't mention the TRQ pin.

Comment: First, you might want to double check your understanding of what a TRQ high or low value means for the torque scalar. Second, I am a little confused - the TRQ pin is part of current regulation. It may be tied to Independent Bridge Interface (IBI) in that you need to figure out if you need current regulation and if so what that regulation looks like, but the TRQ pin itself does not affect the configuration of IBI as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: @InBedded16 Okay, I must need a break because I missed a note underneath Figure 27 (page 28) in the datasheet that says "It is recommended that current regulation not be used for loads using independent half bridges."

Of course, now I'm also questioning whether or not I should be using the Independent Half Bridge config or the 4-pin config, but that's not what my original question is about